# Number recognition show wrong asnwer

Tags: java

i need to write such a network with two layers. The weights are defined in a pretty simple way: 1 for a blue and -1 for a white. For the first output neuron, you should set 15 weights for the number 1, for the second output neuron you should set another 15 weights for the number 2 etc and the last output neuron should recognize the number 0. In the end, you should choose the maximum out of all output neurons and it will be the result of the recognition.
and 
bias is :
6 for 1
0 for 3, 5
1 for 2
2 for 4
3 for 7
-2 for 8
-1 for 6, 9, 0
if i will input 0 then w will be {+1, +1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1}

and i wrote this code but it isnt work correctly can someone explain reason and give some hints

```
int[] w =  {+1, +1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, -1, +1, +1, +1, +1};
        int[] output_num = {0,1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,8,9};
        int[] bias = {-1, 6, 1, 0, 2, 0, -1, 3, -2, -1};
        Integer[] temp =new Integer[10];
        int[] output = new int[10];
        for (int i = 0; i < output_num.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < w.length; j++) {
                temp[i]  = output_num[i] * w[j];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
            temp[i] = temp[i] + bias[i];
        }
for (int x:temp) {
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        }
```

its example when i input 0  its show this result is:-1 7 3 3 6 5 5 10 6 8
how we can see the max result is have index 7 but if i right understand  index should be 0 fro max element can someone give me some hits or explain

Comment: This line is suspicious: `temp[i]  = output_num[i] * w[j];` because it overwrites any previous value in `temp[i]` from previous executions of the `for (int j` loop, making the loop pointless. Maybe it should be a `+=` instead.

Answer (score 0):

You're doing things wrong here , the neural networks doesnt work like this , normally we shouldnt define the weights , they should be adapted using the input and output

You have to initialize them , but they have to be updated ( **Descent of Gradient** ) , suppose you have the following example :

```
input | output
x1    | y1
x2    | y2
```

Then that's how you'll update your weights :

```
w[i] = w[i] + n ( d - yi ) xi
```

where *( d - yi ) = the error* and *n = the learning rate*